# Unable to add items to wxComboBox using std::vector [C++, wxWidgets]

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Tried to do it this way:

File.cpp:

```
void File__Frame::loadCB()
{
   std::vector<std::string> Ids;
   IdTypes.reserve(4);
   IdTypes.push_back("1");
   IdTypes.push_back("2");
   IdTypes.push_back("3");
   IdTypes.push_back("4");
   combobox->Set(Ids);  
}
```

However it is not working, could someone please show me a "corrected" version of this code?

I don't know if that code is wrong or if I need to add something to File__Main.h

Currently, I'm getting this error: `no declaration matches 'void File__Frame::loadCB()'`

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@var_null, please check the widgets or combo sample from the wx distribution.

Also, there is no `wxComboBox::Append(std::vector<std::string>)`